# What is the equivalent of "%[^ ]%" to Teradata?

Tags: teradata

```
if @gl_cst_ctr_cde not like "%[^ ]%"
```

Above is a Sybase code and would like to know the Teradata equivalent of **not like `"%[^ ]%"`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%[^ ]%"` searches for any character other than a space.

So `not like "%[^ ]%"` checks if there are only spaces (or it's an empty string)

In TD14 you could use a Regular Expression (REGEXP_SIMILAR) for LIKEs with character ranges, but in this case it should be exactly the same as a simple `@gl_cst_ctr_cde = ''`

Comment: Hi again, would like to follow up a question. is the @gl_cst_ctr_cde = '' has space inside, like '  '    or just '' without the space?thanks

Comment: @Gemudesu: This checks for both, an empty string or a series of spaces, simply try it.